# iPhone app rejected - due to iPad crash, targeted device family was set to iPhone only

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, appstore-approval

My iPhone app was rejected today, due to a memory issue when tested on an iPad device.

> We found that your app crashed on launch while installed on iPad (3rd
>   Gen) running iOS 6.1.3, which is not in compliance with the App Store
>   Review Guidelines.
>
> Your app may encounter this issue if it is using too much memory. To
>   learn more about iOS memory usage and how to track memory usage and
>   leaks, please see the Memory Usage Performance Guidelines.

The weird thing is, my targeted device family was set to iPhone only.

Anyone have any ideas why they'd still test it on an iPad device?

Regard,
Sally

Comment: Can you post the full explanation for rejection and describe a little bit about your application architecture? They may have tested it on iPad as an iPhone app running 2x but I don't see why it would specifically crash on an iPad vs an iPhone.

Comment: Please check the "Binary Details" in iTunes Connect. There you can see which target device was uploaded in *.ipa file. We thought to target iPhone only but it was targeted for both as we saw later on. And maybe you have more details and some screenshots.

Answer (score 7):

Because iPhone apps run on iPad. But not the opposite. This allows the iPad to have more apps because the iPhone app can be run in 2x mode.

Check instrument while running your app in the iPad simulator to discover leaks.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I tested my app, and it crashed on 2x mode hence the rejection , I needed to fix my storyboards, added one for iPad and It was fine, no error then.

Comment: Nice! I am glad I could help. You can show the love by selecting this as the correct answer. ;-)